# группировка данных в словаре Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dict

есть ли возможность как то группировать данные в словаре?

```
# данные на выходе
data = [
    {'release-1': 'Pass'},
    {'release-2': 'Conditionally Passed'},
    {'release-1': 'Pass'},
    {'release-1': 'Pass'},
    {'release-1': 'Conditionally Passed'}
]
```

я использовал код:

```
groupdict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for dict_ in data:
    for value in dict_.items():
        group = value[0]
        value = value[1]
        groupdict[group].append(value)
        groupdict[value].append(value)
result = {group: len(values) for group, values in groupdict.items()}
```

```
# то что получилось в результате группировки
result = {
    'release-1': 2,
    'Pass': 3,
    'release-2': 3,
    'Conditionally Passed': 2
}
```

ВОПРОС: Можно получить что-то подобное?

```
# Желательно получить в таком виде
results = {
    'release-1': [{'Pass': 3}],
    'release-2': [
        {'Conditionally Passed': 1},
        {'Pass': 1}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

results = {k: Counter(i[1] for i in v)
           for k, v in groupby(sorted(((k, v)
                                       for i in data
                                       for k, v in i.items()),
                                      key=itemgetter(0)),
                               key=itemgetter(0))}
```